# Running Play framework 2.1.1 and getting "exception when typing play.Project.javaCore"

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm trying out the sample apps that come bundled with the play download and they appear not to be working, but the exception I'm getting isn't clear about what's going on.

I've previously been able to create new applications in Play ok, so this seems a bit odd.

I switched to the samples folder and simply trying running "play":

```
$ cd ~/play-2.1.1/samples/java/helloworld/
$ play
```

Which should bring up the play console.

Instead I get this output + exception:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/john/play-2.1.1/samples/java/helloworld/project
exception when typing play.Project.javaCore
class file needed by PlayReloader is missing.
reference type SBTLink of package play.core refers to nonexisting symbol. in file /home/john/play-2.1.1/samples/java/helloworld/project/Build.scala
scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeError: class file needed by PlayReloader is missing.
reference type SBTLink of package play.core refers to nonexisting symbol.
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.UnPickler$CompileScan.toTypeError(UnPickler.scala:66)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.UnPickler$CompileScan$LazyTypeRef.complete(UnPickler.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.UnPickler$CompileScan$LazyTypeRef.load(UnPickler.scala:81)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.typeParams(Symbols.scala:913)
 ... <rest omitted for brevity> ...
[error] (compile:compile) java.lang.Error
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

It looks like it's not resolving a dependency or something as it's complaining that it's can't find a specific class (SBTLink?)?  But really not so sure what's going on here.

Anyone got any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: actually this appears to be happening for other play projects - so it's not specific to the sample apps.

I've just been able to make a new app ok (using "play new"), but when I switch into it's folder and run "play" I get the same exception as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the end I had to delete the repository cache - I'm guessing it'd got corrupted somehow.  Which would explain why it was complaining about not being able to find some class files.

Another possibility about why it stopped working may be due updates to java itself.  There had been at least one update to java (to 1.7.0_25 on ubuntu) since I last tried running play, so there may have been some issue there (perhaps minor binary class file change?).

My play folder is in my home directory, so I did the following:

```
$ cd ~/play-2.1.1/
$ rm -r repository/cache/
```

Then tried running play again inside one of the sample app folders.  It took a while (presumably as it was rebuilding the cache) and then worked.